# Conditional passing Touch event to underneath view

Tags: android

I have a layout hierarchy with `RelativeLayout` on top of a `ViewPager` like:

```
<FrameLayout>

  <ViewPager/>       
  <RelativeLayout/>   

</FrameLayout>
```

I have a `View.OnTouchListener` on `RelativeLayout`. 
I want to handle the TouchEvent on this view hierarchy. What i want is, as user started to scroll along Y-axis then all further TouchEvent should be pass to `RelativeLayout` or as user started to scroll along X-axis then Touch should be handle by `ViewPager`.

Comment: It seems like you need to put the RelativeLayout inside the fragment shown by ViewPager otherwise it doesn't make sense for UX unless you have BottomSheet like behavior

Comment: `ViewPager` already have its separate content and `RelativeLayout`  contains some views that always appear on top of `ViewPager`

Comment: also i have updated the question a little. Please see if relevant.

Comment: see `ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent`

Comment: You can do it using `onInterceptTouchEvent` as suggested in the previous comment but it doesn't really make sense interaction wise. Swipe/scroll events on views which are on top of other views should not propagate down otherwise there's no point in placing them on 'top' of other views

Comment: @pskink @akash93 thank you both.Now going to read how this `onInterceptTouchEvent()`  works.